Error when trying to knitting a gif animation
I have made an earthquake map, then I made it to gif animation. But when i tried to knitting it to html it show an error "! unable to start png() device". It works when i tried knitting the png image of the EQ_map but not for the gif. It also work perfectly in Rmarkdown but problem occurs when i tried knitiing it to html. Any solution?
timelapse_EQMap <- EQ_Map +
  labs(subtitle = "{{closest_state}}",
  transition_states(Date, transition_length = 1, state_length = 1, wrap = FALSE)

# Defining the output parameters for the animation
animated <- animate(
  timelapse_EQMap, 
  fps = 10,                    
  width = 600,                 
  height = 410,
  res = 100,
  renderer = gifski_renderer() 
)

# Saving the animation as a GIF
gganimate::anim_save("EQ_Map.gif", animated)

# Displaying the GIF in R Markdown
knitr::include_graphics("EQ_Map.gif")

Showing both png of the map and gif animation in html output
